# Reference for results p-adic integers Z_p as abelian group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I have two facts I want to use in my thesis about $\mathbb{Z}_p$. To be precise: automorphism group is $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$, except for 2, and that any subgroup with finite index is of the form $p^m\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Ofcourse I could just prove these results, but I dont want to define $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or anything. I assume the reader knows it, but I just want to recall these facts. Not all readers may know everything, so a reference for these results seems a good idea.

However, I could not find any books  about p-adic integers, only those who define it using the p-adic norm. Also topology and p-adic analysis was plenty available. Does anybody know a good book or article as a reference for my results? Or maybe some big books covering group theory which might contain it?

Comment: For the automorphism group see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30572/what-is-the-automorphism-group-of-the-additive-group-of-the-p-adic-integers).

Comment: I dont think a reference to this website would be a proper reference, dont you think?

Comment: I know many theses now which do have a MO-reference. However, in your case, the book of [Gouvea](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540629115) is perhaps helpful. The above link gives more references, e.g., Serre's book.

Comment: Maybe I will if no other resource is available. Also I have looked in that book already! I scrolled through it quickly and could not find what I was looking for. Maybe I overlooked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the automorphism group of the additive group of the ring of $p$-adic integers as Example $2$, page $318$ in [this book](https://books.google.at/books?id=kwvGp9_4lOMC&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=automorphism+group+of+additive+group+of+p-adic+integers&source=bl&ots=tNZmyk3vTL&sig=bXmBJQrDX8HL5zxEpFOB1vKASwY&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6i5iv1-HNAhXGbhQKHYaeB4wQ6AEIWzAI#v=onepage&q=automorphism%20group%20of%20additive%20group%20of%20p-adic%20integers&f=false) on Abelian Group Theory. Also a reference to the [MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30572/what-is-the-automorphism-group-of-the-additive-group-of-the-p-adic-integers) is possible, I think.